# Reading Hive managed table from Java Map Reduce code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I want to read a managed Hive table data form my map reduce job.
I have a managed Hive table which was created from another table which was created from an external hive table. I want to run a map reduce job on my final managed Hive table. I read that managed have tables have a separator that defaults to the "char 1" ASCII character.
so i did this:

```
public static final String SEPARATOR_FIELD = new String(new char[] {1});
```

and later I did this in a loop:

```
end = rowTextObject.find(SEPARATOR_FIELD, start);
```

But when I run the map reduce jar, I get Illegal Argument exception at the above line and the line given below:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text rowTextObject, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

PS: I looked up a project on github for reading a managed hive table in mapreduce job, but I cannot make sense of that @ https://github.com/facebook/hive-io-experimental.

Comment: Have you looked into [HCatalog](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_19_6.html)?

Comment: You can actually take the file which is loaded into the hive table and run a mapreduce on that. Take that paticular file and add into your input path and then do what ever you want to do in mapreduce like a typical map reduce job

Comment: @Binary01 - Yes, I know that. So the problem is I'm not able to parse the file that is loaded into the hive table as described above.

Comment: What is your hive.default.fileformat ? I can bet lunch money it is a SequenceFile. Do you configure your MapReduce job to read sequence files?

Comment: @climbage - I'm checking out Hcatalog and trying to make sense of it. It looks like a bunch of code read.

Comment: @Olaf - I think the format is text because when I do 'hadoop fs -cat filename' I get readable english letters. (The original files were in sequence snappy format, but I think when I create a Hive table from the managed Hive table that references the seq-snappy format, the new format is in Text.) I don't know how to check the hive.default.fileformat though(I'm using Cloudera too, but I don't have all the permissions.)

Comment: You can use SHOW CREATE TABLE to get the detailed information about your table, including file storage details.

Comment: @Olaf - Okay. I did that. The format is Text. To be precise the input format is 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' and the output format is 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

Comment: You can try out a trick before taking the data into map reduce. (Option 1) You can replace the delimiter which is creating problem with hive default delimiter or comma using sed or any other linux command. (Option 2) You can load this table into a temporary single column table in hive and then do a REGEX_REPLACE udf to replace your problematic delimiter i.e (char 1 of ASCII) with hive default delimiter or comma. and then take this file and process in map reduce

Comment: @Binary01 - I think the linux command is not feasible cause the data is huge and hence the need to use Hadoop in the first place. Option 2, I don't really like and I don't have a good reason apart from it not being very Big Data like? I mean it shouldn't be that hard to directly parse a hive table in a MR job. Btw, I think char 1 of ASCII is the default hive delimiter.

Comment: There is a good reason why Hive is usually configured to store data as sequence files. Rather than having to make a space/perfromance trade off, you are getting both space and perfromance benefits with the compressed sequence files.

Comment: Okay. I'm still clueless as to how to use HCatalog @climbage. I'm using Cloudera's instance and I used Hive to create the table.

Comment: Actually the problem you are facing should not be an issue at all as I have also parsed similar files which has default hive delimiter but I dont know why you are facing problem in parsing.It should be simple parsing in map method

Comment: @Binary01 - Glad to hear it. Can you go through my two lines of code above? I'm getting Illegal argument exception and I have no idea why. Can you share the code to parse such files? Or some good links? I have referred this link for my code to read hive tables - https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/reading-hive-tables-from-mapreduce. The only difference it that I have set the key to NullWritable instead of BytesWritable (Cause a null BytesWritable would raise a NullPOinterException)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have the input file as below (say xyz.txt):-
111 **\001** 222 
121 **\001** 222
131 **\001** 222
141 **\001** 222
151 **\001** 222
161 **\001** 222
171 **\001** 222
 Now **\001** is my hive default delimiter(say).
Now in order to parse this file which is already loaded to hive table using map reduce I will do something like this in my map method:-

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context) throws java.io.IOException ,InterruptedException
    {

        String[]vals=value.toString().split("\\001");
        context.write(new Text(vals[0]),new Text("1"));
     }

}
```

Your driver method will be normal one as follows:-

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(xyz.txt));
```

So the final output will be as follows based on my map method that I have given :-
111 1
121 1
131 1
141 1
151 1
161 1
171 1
It this what your are looking for like the parsing I am doing in my map method?

Comment: The split() will consume consecutive delimiters form what I read. So that would not do a good job because, I have NULL values in the hive table. If my 5th column is null, my 6th column shifts up to the 5th column for that record. (Btw, From what I read, The default hive delimiter is Char 1 of ASCII and when I do hadoop fs -cat, I can see that the values do not have delimiters between them. I think this is cause Char 1 of ASCII is a no-op)

Comment: What I think if your 5th column is null your 6th column wont shift to 5th.can you try the code I gave and parse your table and let me know that got shifted.

Comment: Okay. I tried it.  String[] columnArray = line.split(SEPARATOR_FIELD);...and..word = new Text(columnArray[0] + "\t" + columnArray[1]);  ..and word was emitted by the mapper but the output is blank. I think that this is because Char1 of ASCII is no op and not recognized in strings?